# Spring - run @Scheduled dynamically n times

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

How to run @Scheduled n times, based on number of companies I have in application?
For example method sendMail should run every day but in different time for every company I have in application.

1. Run method every day at X(based on information from database) for company A (based on information from database)

   ```
   @Scheduled(cron="#{@getCronValue}")
       public void sendMail() {
          ... send mail for company A
   }
   ```
2. Run method every day at Y(based on information from database) for company B (based on information from database)

N. Run n times (number of companies)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that @Scheduled is a direct solution to your problem. I would recommend the following approach:

1. create some sort of persistence mechanism (DB table, collection, ...)
2. store a "job object" for each company (include the company identifier and the time the job should be executed)
3. use @Scheduled to find jobs that should be executed
4. call sendMail(company) for each job

You could use existing solutions like https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler or Quartz Scheduler for this as well.